# Can concating two strings show resulting string

Tags: typescript

for the code:

```
const a = "url";
const b = "/route";
const c = a + b;
```

typescript knows the exact values of `a` and `b`, and since they're const, they're unchangeable. However, when concating both strings, `c` just shows a generic `string` type.

Is it possible for `c` to show `url/route` instead?

[image]
[image]

Comment: This I think has to do more with intellisense of the editor.

Comment: @PratikWadekar no, it's TS: [Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhjAvDARAVwE4BsUG4CwAUAPTEzkwB6A-EaJLAEZKrEYhpQCmeRpFVWoXrQYwFggDUMRgRJkKNIA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to infer literal type you need to use extra function for concatenation:

```js
const a = "url";

const b = "/route";

const c = a + b;


const concat = <
    A extends string,
    B extends string
>(a: A, b: B): `${A}${B}` => `${a}${b}`

const result = concat(a, b) // "url/route"
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/WJyblm)

In order to make type inference safe, in this case, you need to avoid using `+` (plus) for string concatenation.

Answer (score -1):

The value of c is being updated on the runtime and if you print the log you will notice that the value of c is "url/route" its just that when you try to hover over c with the cursor since that code hasn't processed the result it doesn't display the updated value of c instead it shows the data type of variable value.